# Angula2/Node js - Requiring modules outside of app directory

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, angular

I'm trying to import module from js file and within my component and it fails with the following error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)**

My solution structure (you can also look at my test [example](https://github.com/dev4201/couchbase-angular2-test/tree/master/couchbase-angular2-test) at github:

```
>/
>/model
>  testModel.js
>/public
>  /app
>    app.component.ts
>    main.ts
>app.js
>package.json
```

**This Fails in app.component.ts**

```
var test = require("../../testModel");
```

**testModel.js**

```
    /// <reference path="../typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />
    (function () {
        module.exports.config = "testing config";

     })();
```

But if I move /model directory to /app dir it works. So bottom line, I'm unable to import any module that is not part of /app directory, except for Angular 2 and such..

**My app.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes.index);
```

**index.html**

```
 System.config({
            packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' }           
            }
        });
        System.import('app/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why when you leave `/models` in your app root it doesn't work is because you're not serving it as a static asset.

If you want to keep it there and not place it in your `/public` directory then you need to add it as a static resource within your express app.

Add the following line before your routes with the rest of your middleware

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'models')));`

Comment: Thank you for your advise, it did the trick! - in addition to your resolution in /app/app.component.ts I had to add .js for the imported resource [var test = require("../../testModel.js") ]- I hope that helps someone else.